# Selecting parcels with multiple features

Tags: select-by-attribute, select-by-location

So i have a parcel polygon layer and a house point layer. I want to select parcels that have two or more points in them? Any suggestions?

Comment: What software do you have for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the QGIS *[Count Points in Polygon](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/countpointsinpolygon.html)* tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to ArcGIS, you could do a spatial join as described on this page: http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779

Then just select polygons where the count field is larger than 1.

Comment: Thats what I was just going to say. I'm sure that you can also do a spatial join in QGIS.